# Dual boot with two separate drives

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uninstall

I currently have my computer setup dual booting ubuntu and windows 8.1. Both operating systems are installed on separate physical drives.

My question is that now I have a new laptop (which I will be using exclusively for Ubuntu), how can I remove the dual boot set up from my computer (and keep windows 8.1 in tact)? Is there a simple way I can 'fix' the bootloader back to Windows and then just format the drive with Ubuntu on?

Comment: >  Both operating systems are installed on separate physical drives.

This is not a dual boot. A dual boot means Two OS on the same drive. Are you sure of your configuraiton?

Comment: Have you tried boot off the Windows disk via some function key at startup?  If grub was installed to the second disk, and it was given boot order priority, the Windows bootloader may still be sitting unused on the first disk.

Comment: Thanks @ubfan1 - that solved it for me....but I can't accept your answer as a comment(!) If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot off the Windows disk via some function key at startup. If grub was installed to the second disk, and it was given boot order priority, the Windows bootloader will still be sitting unused on the first disk.

Answer (score 0):

To clear Ubuntu from your dual-boot hard drive computer, you have to:

1. Put in your recovery disk or Windows Installation Disk, or make one. You should see this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

After you get these menus, click command prompt and type this command in:
**bootrec /fixmbr**

[image]

Now, you can uninstall Ubuntu without GRUB messing with your stuff.

To delete the Ubuntu Partitions:

Go to Start, right click Computer, then select Manage. Then select Disk Management from the sidebar.

[image]

The picture above is just an example, but to UN-install Ubuntu, right click the Ubuntu partition on your other hard disk drive and delete it.

**WARNING: YOU WILL LOSE ALL DATA ON THAT HARD DISK IF YOU DON'T HAVE SEPARATE PARTITIONS. BE VERY CAUTIOUS ABOUT WHICH ONE YOU'LL DELETE.**
You'll be good to go. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Any tool which can write a Windows MBR can do.

For example using Windows boot sector utility:

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS /mbr
```

bootsect.exe is part of Windows 8 and later. Earlier it was only available on Windows recovery console.

For cleaning a disk the Windows command "diskpart.exe" can be used.

> diskpart
>
> list disk  (this lists disks with size info)
>
> select disk n  (n is disk number to be cleaned - use size as hint)
>
> clean (this clears MBR or GPT formatting)

This solution uses only standard utilities available when running Windows 8 so you don't need recovery console.